# How to extract numerical (or string) data from wikipedia tables via webscraping?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I would like to use `BeautifulSoup` to webscrape data from wikipedia articles for the purpose of creating an HR Diagram. For the example below, I have chosen the star named Arcturus, though the purpose of the code is to be general enough to work for (almost?) any star. The rightmost table of the wikipedia page for each star contains all the information necessary to construct the diagram.

As an example, consider the [wikipedia page for Arcturus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcturus). The spectral type can be found under the `Characteristics` subheader; the absolute magnitude can be found under the `Astrometry` subheader; the luminosity and temperature can be found under the `Details` subheader. Since all of this information is contained within the same main table, I tried the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hyperlink = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcturus'
webdata = requests.get(hyperlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webdata.text, 'lxml')
# print("\nPRETTY SOUP:\n{}\n".format(soup.prettify()))

res = []
right_table = soup.find('table', class_='infobox')
for row in right_table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    print("\n .. CELLS:\n{}\n".format(cells))
```

This code will run a separate `print` command for each row of the table. I used `ctrl + f` to find the occurrences of the word "temperature", from which I found the relevant `print` statement:

```
 .. CELLS:
[<td><b><a href="/wiki/Effective_temperature" title="Effective temperature">Temperature</a></b></td>, <td><span class="nowrap"><span data-sort-value="7003428600000000000♠"></span>4286<span style="margin-left:0.3em;margin-right:0.15em;">±</span>30</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ramirez_prieto_2011_7-3"><a href="#cite_note-ramirez_prieto_2011-7">[7]</a></sup> <a href="/wiki/Kelvin" title="Kelvin">K</a></td>]
```

The actual value is `4286 ± 30 K`. Is there an easy-to-generalize method to parse this html string? I would like to believe the methods to extract the other relevant parameters (such as spectral type) will not be much different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract just specific information, you could use this as example (using [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to obtain info):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hyperlink = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcturus'
webdata = requests.get(hyperlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webdata.text, 'lxml')

def remove_sup(tag):
    for s in tag.select('sup'):
        s.extract()
    return tag

spectral = remove_sup(soup.select_one(":matches(td, th):contains('Spectral') + td")).get_text(strip=True)
magnitude = remove_sup(soup.select_one(":matches(td, th):contains('Absolute') + td")).get_text(strip=True)
lum = remove_sup(soup.select_one(":matches(td, th):contains('Luminosity') + td")).get_text(strip=True)
temp = remove_sup(soup.select_one(":matches(td, th):contains('Temperature') + td")).get_text(strip=True)

print('{: <25}{}'.format('Spectral type :', spectral))
print('{: <25}{}'.format('Absolute magnitude :', magnitude))
print('{: <25}{}'.format('Luminosity :', lum))
print('{: <25}{}'.format('Temperature :', temp))
```

Prints:

```
Spectral type :          K0 III
Absolute magnitude :     −0.30±0.02
Luminosity :             170L☉
Temperature :            4286±30K
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
for row in right_table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = ' '.join([i.get_text() for i in row.findAll('td')])
    print(cells)
```

But you are going to get the super scripts and sub scripts for example.